# NVidia GForce 1070 - Multiple Monitors max resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors

This may be a stupid question, so I apologize up front.

NVidia's website says the `Maximum Digital Resolution` for my video card is 7680x4320.

Does that mean that is the MAXIMUM resolution it can support for **each** of the 4 monitors?

Or

Does that mean that **combined**, the monitors cannot exceed that resolution?

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1070-ti/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per monitor, as that's the maximum a single Displayport 1.4 port can provide.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits_for_DisplayPort)

For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tAa0qbAYK4) show a Titan X (Maxwell) pushing 3x4K displays with the card [listing a Maximum Digital Resolution of 5120x3200](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-titan-x/specifications).